# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement Python - MySql

Tags: python, mysql

I want to check if the ID exists already but I get this error:

`Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

**Code:**

```
Id = "TEST"
sql = """SELECT * FROM musics WHERE Id = %s"""
dbc.execute(sql, Id)

row = cursor.rowcount
if row == 0:
    #NOT EXSIST
```

Comment: You need to put `Id` in a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `execute()` should be a sequence of values, one for each placeholder token `%s` in the query.

You did pass a sequence, but not in the way you intended.  Strings are sequences, so you actually passed a sequence of *four* values - `T, E, S, T`, which is too many values, because the query only has one placeholder token.

Pass the string as a one-element tuple, like so:

```
args = ("TEST",)
sql = """SELECT * FROM musics WHERE Id = %s"""
dbc.execute(sql, args)
```